# Is it possible to pass a struct to a function without creating a variable?

Tags: c

In C++ this code is valid

```
struct foo{
    int x;
};

int bar(foo f);

bar({1});
```

However I get an error when I try to do something similar in C. Is there way a to pass a struct to a function without actually creating a variable for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a **compound literal** for this:

```
bar((struct foo){1});
```